# Issue using custom loader in angular-translate

Tags: angularjs

I am implementing a portal where multiple modules will be plugged in. These will be implemented as angular modules. Each module will have its own localizable resource strings. I am using angular-translate for loading the resources.

I am facing a issue when using custom loader. I think its angular-translate behavior that once resources are loaded for a culture it does not try and load resources for that culture again. So in my case the loader only loads resources in the root module and it does not execute the loaders for any of my child modules.

Is there any way of forcing angular-translate to execute all the loaders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use partial loading for that: https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/12_asynchronous-loading (look under "Partial Loading").

Comment: the given URL is expired

Answer (score 0):

Updated link to the partial loading documentation mentioned by PascalPrecht: http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/12_asynchronous-loading/#asynchronous-loading_using-partialloader